# Sums of operators in practice

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, harmonic-oscillator

Consider a one dimensional harmonic oscillator.

We have:
 $$\hat{n} = \hat{a}^{\dagger} \hat{a} = \frac{m \omega}{2 \hbar} \hat{x}^2 + \frac{1}{2 \hbar m \omega} \hat{p}^2 - \frac{1}{2}$$
And:
 $$\hat{H} = \hbar \omega (\hat{n} + \frac{1}{2})$$

Let's say we want to measure the total energy.

We can, using the number operator $\hat{n}$. However this operator is ultimately defined as a linear combination of $\hat{x}^2$ and $\hat{p}^2$ (and $\hat{I}$), or as the product of  $\hat{a}^{\dagger}$ and $\hat{a}$; both of which are functions of $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$.

So **apparently**, this requires (by the definition above) that we measure location and momentum in two separate identical systems.

This raises a question:

The **apparent** requirement of interacting with two independent systems in order to calculate/measure the number of quanta in **a** system has to be wrong. ?

And finally: How does one measure total energy or number of quanta in reality?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite see why would have to measure *twice*. Could you elaborate?

Comment: @Danu As far as my current understanding goes: Operating an operator (that corresponds to an observable) on a wave function is a theoretical formulation of measuring the actual system with a corresponding apparatus. So, a square of an operator is actually measuring and then measuring again. Wrong?

Comment: Yes, wrong :) You don't have to measure twice. You just take the value you measured and square it ;)

Comment: Which is essentially the same of operating twice.. My mistake. So, what about the second question? :)

Comment: Well, I think you can measure the energy of the system *directly*, so you don't *have* to use multiple identically prepared systems.

Comment: Oh, and it's important to note that the systems *definitely* should not interact!

Comment: That's what I thought. But, all observables are in fact functions of $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$.. So this question needs to be replaced by a better one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The action of an operator is not equivalent to performing a measurement. For example, for a spin-1/2 particle in the eigenstate "spin up along z", measuring spin along y produces either the eigenstate "spin up along y" or "spin down along y". But the action of $\hat{S}_y$ on "spin up along z" creates a superposition of the two spin y eigenstates.

I'll address your last point first. If we want to measure the energy, then unless we have a system prepared in a state of well defined energy, we are at the mercy of statistics. We can say something about the expected value of the measurement though. If the system is in a general state $|\Psi\rangle$

$$\langle \hat{H}\rangle=\langle\Psi|\alpha\hat{x}^2+\beta\hat{p}^2|\Psi\rangle=\alpha\langle\Psi|\hat{x}^2|\Psi\rangle+\beta\langle\Psi|\hat{p}^2|\Psi\rangle=\alpha\langle\hat{x}^2\rangle +\beta\langle \hat{p}^2\rangle$$

We can calculate the expectation of $\hat{p}^2$ by expressing $|\Psi\rangle$ an eigenbasis of $\hat{p}$: $|\Psi\rangle=\sum_{p'}|p'\rangle\langle p'|\Psi\rangle$. Then $$\langle\Psi|\hat{p}^2|\Psi\rangle=\int dp''\int dp'\langle\Psi|p''\rangle\langle p''|\hat{p}^2|p'\rangle\langle p'|\Psi\rangle$$

$$ =\int dp''\int dp'\Psi^*(p'')\Psi(p')p'^2\delta(p'-p'') $$

$$ = \int_{p'}p'^2|\Psi(p')|^2$$

we just need the wavefuntion for the system expressed in momentum space (which is the fourier transform  of the real space wave function). For $\langle\hat{x}\rangle$ the expression is

$$ \langle\hat{x}^2\rangle=\int x^2|\Psi(x)|^2dx  $$

So as long as we know the wave function we can calculate the expectation value of the energy. For example, we may have a Gaussian wave packet centred on the origin.

Coming back to your 2 initial concerns: Firstly, $\hat{x}^2$ is just saying apply the operator twice (not measure twice). When calculating the expectation value, if we are in an eigenstate of the operator $\hat{x}$ we just get $\langle\hat{x}^2\rangle=x^2$.

Secondly, we're not interacting with anything just by writing down the hamiltonian. Measuring the energy of the system is a single interaction with the system, but by the very nature of quantum mechanics we can't necessarily be sure what value we will get. However, we can calculate the expectation value of that measurement and it involves applying operators to states mathematically.

Comment: I think the "y" at the end of the first paragraph needs to be "z"?

Comment: No, it's a y. $S_y|s_z=1/2\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|s_y=-1/2\rangle+|s_y=1/2\rangle)$.

Comment: But staying in the $S_z$ basis $S_y|s_z=1/2\rangle=i|s_z=-1/2\rangle$ (with appropriate  scale factors)